# Odoo 10 call old api method

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

I am using Odoo 10 and trying override stock **quants_get_preferred_domain** method.

My code:

```
@api.v7
def quants_get_preferred_domain(self, cr, uid, qty, move, ops=False,  lot_id=False, domain=None, preferred_domain_list=[], context=None):
```

And I am getting an error:

```
  File "/opt/odoo10/addons/stock/models/stock_move.py", line 660, in action_assign
    quants = Quant.quants_get_preferred_domain(qty, move, domain=main_domain[move.id], preferred_domain_list=[])
TypeError: quants_get_preferred_domain() takes at least 5 arguments (5 given)
```

What can be wring with decorators and how correctly on v10 can I call old api method?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are changing the method decorator definition from `@api.model` to `@api.v7`

You could check that in the code of the method [quants_get_preferred_domain](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/stock/models/stock_quant.py#L382). You should be ok defining the method override as:

```
@api.model
def quants_get_preferred_domain(self, qty, move, ops=False, lot_id=False, domain=None, preferred_domain_list=[]):
```

You should also check if your Odoo version is outdated that may have some issues solved in earlier Odoo 10 versions

Comment: Yeah, I know that Odoo 10 has the same name method but the logic is different and using Odoo 10 quants_get_preferred_domain quants are reserving randomly.

Comment: You could override it with your own code as suggested to provide your own behavior but you should respect the decorator and method definition and args to be able to let the method called by Odoo in the same way as the original